# No background on downarrow-beside-username popup on main page, but it is there on question pages

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

If I go to superuser.com and mouse over the arrow near my name, it's hard to read because there is no background.  I click through to a question, and on that page there is no problem.

[image: main page]

[image: question page]

This is on Web+ on Haiku.  It's WebKit-based.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure [Web+ is a supported browser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: @Sathya, thanks, I neglected to look for such criteria.  Can anyone confirm whether this happens on a WebKit-based browser having more market share?  :-)

Comment: Doesn't happen in Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) on OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: Nor Chrome standard on Win7SP1.  Hmm.  I wonder what would make the difference?  Default CSS?  Well, I'll go report it with the Haiku devs.